# Is (a*b) or (a*b)* star-free?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, kleene-star

Here is the proof of a∗ being star-free:

$\Sigma* = \bar{\emptyset} $

$ A∗= \overline{Σ∗(Σ∖A)Σ∗} $

Would this be a proof for $a * b$? :
$ A∗B= \overline{Σ∗(Σ∖A)Σ∗(Σ∖B)} $

For $(A * B )*$ it seems more complicated if not impossible, but is that proofable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^*b = (a^*)\cdot b$

$(a^*b)^* = \{\varepsilon\} \cup \{a,b\}^* b$

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that star-free languages are closed regarding boolean operators / concatenation. I assume $\{A,B\}* = \overline{\Sigma*((\Sigma∖A)\cup(\Sigma∖B))\Sigma*}$?
If you have time to spare, would you mind telling me whether (a+ b)∗ is non-star free or whether I could alter that grammar easily to obtain a non-star free grammar?

More importan: do you know the dot-depth of those two grammars? Do I simply write out the extended form without the star and then count how often boolean expressions and concatenation alternate? I.e. for a*b it would be 2 and for (a*b)* its 2 or 2.5?

Comment: It seems that $(a^+b)^* = (a^*\cdot ab)^*$ is helpful here. Note that star-free languages are first-order definable, thus "every $b$ is preceded by $a$ and last letter is $b$". I am not familiar enough with dot-depth to answer.